# sscanf format parameter not working

Tags: c++, string, user-input, scanf

The user inputs a string in a specified format

> K i v
>
> K is a string
>
> i is an int
>
> v is an int

---

> Example: "K 100 2"
>
> char char_cmd = K
>
> int a = 100
>
> int b = 2

```
cout << "Input your command to perfrom operation: " << endl
cin >> input;
sscanf(input.c_str(),"%s %d %d",&char_cmd,&a,&b);
```

I get the value for char_cmd no problem
When it comes to the ints a & b it doesnt seem to copy what the user inputs

I looked around and it seems that white spaces are the problem

What can i do to accomplish this?

Comment: afaik mixing c and c++ i/o is in general not the best idea. Why do you use `scanf` here?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Off topic: Check the return value of `sscanf`. It will contain how many values were actually read and interpreted.

Comment: `cin >> char_cmd >>a >> b;` seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: Please clarify the type of `char_cmd`. If it is `std::string`, know that `sscanf` is a C function. It has no understanding of C++ constructs like `std::string`.

Comment: @user4581301 char_cmd is a char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char char_cmd;
int a;
int b;
char input[100];

cin.getline(input,sizeof(input));
sscanf(input,"%c %d %d",&char_cmd,&a,&b);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Discard

```
cin >> input;
sscanf(input.c_str(),"%s %d %d",&char_cmd,&a,&b);
```

and replace it with

```
cin >> char_cmd >>a >> b;
```

Why what OP has here will not work:

Problem 1:

```
cin >> input;
```

reads exactly one whitespace delimited token. Given OP's sample input, "K 100 2", input contains "K". That's all. Look into `std::getline` to read more than one word at a time.

Problem 2:

In

```
sscanf(input.c_str(),"%s %d %d",&char_cmd,&a,&b);
```

`sscanf` has been instructed to

1. `%s` parse a whitespace delimited string and store it in `char_cmd`
2. `%d` parse a signed integer and store it in `a`
3. `%d` parse a signed integer and store it in `b`

OP has just clarified in their comments that `char_cmd` is a `char`, not a buffer capable of containing a null terminated string. Reading so much as one character will take two `char`s, one for the character read and one for the null. Undefined behaviour results.

Because a pointer to an array of `char` and a pointer to a `char` look exactly the same, `sscanf` cannot detect the mistake. Actually, because `sscanf` takes variable arguments it can't detect a lot of mistakes. That's reason number one not to use it.